CImg.h inside a HIP project compilation
I am currently able to compile CImg.h using g++ but not using HIPCC with same arguments
Here is an example of warning that does not happen with g++
./CImg.h:65055:7: warning: length modifier 'I64' results in undefined behavior or no effect with 'u' conversion
      specifier [-Wformat]
      _cimg_load_cimg_case("bool",0,0,cimg_uint8);

And here is examples of linking errors
lld-link: error: undefined symbol: __declspec(dllimport) EnumDisplaySettingsA
>>> referenced by C:\Users\leofr\AppData\Local\Temp\base-fd6cb1.o:(int __cdecl cimg_library::cimg::dialog<unsigned char>(char const *const, char const *const, char const *const, char const *const, char const *const, char const *const, char const *const, char const *const, struct cimg_library::CImg<unsigned char> const &, bool))
>>> referenced by C:\Users\leofr\AppData\Local\Temp\base-fd6cb1.o:(int __cdecl cimg_library::cimg::dialog<unsigned char>(char const *const, char const *const, char const *const, char const *const, char const *const, char const *const, char const *const, char const *const, struct cimg_library::CImg<unsigned char> const &, bool))
>>> referenced by C:\Users\leofr\AppData\Local\Temp\base-fd6cb1.o:(public: struct cimg_library::CImgDisplay & __cdecl cimg_library::CImgDisplay::_assign(unsigned int, unsigned int, char const *const, unsigned int, bool, bool))
>>> referenced 4 more times

lld-link: error: undefined symbol: __declspec(dllimport) SetWindowPos
>>> referenced by C:\Users\leofr\AppData\Local\Temp\base-fd6cb1.o:(int __cdecl cimg_library::cimg::dialog<unsigned char>(char const *const, char const *const, char const *const, char const *const, char const *const, char const *const, char const *const, char const *const, struct cimg_library::CImg<unsigned char> const &, bool))
>>> referenced by C:\Users\leofr\AppData\Local\Temp\base-fd6cb1.o:(public: struct cimg_library::CImgDisplay & __cdecl cimg_library::CImgDisplay::resize(int, int, bool))
>>> referenced by C:\Users\leofr\AppData\Local\Temp\base-fd6cb1.o:(public: struct cimg_library::CImgDisplay & __cdecl cimg_library::CImgDisplay::resize(int, int, bool))

lld-link: error: undefined symbol: __declspec(dllimport) DestroyWindow
>>> referenced by C:\Users\leofr\AppData\Local\Temp\base-fd6cb1.o:(public: struct cimg_library::CImgDisplay & __cdecl cimg_library::CImgDisplay::assign(void))
>>> referenced by C:\Users\leofr\AppData\Local\Temp\base-fd6cb1.o:(public: struct cimg_library::CImgDisplay & __cdecl cimg_library::CImgDisplay::assign(void))

I tried a lot of things but was not able to make it link properly.
I would like to precise that this does not happen when I am just including CImg.h
#include<iostream>
//#include "test.cpp" was where I wanted to put isolated gpu code to use here
#include "CImg.h"

int main(){
    cimg_library::CImg<unsigned char> img("img/test.jpg");

    return 0;
}

It happens once I start using it in my code
Do you have any ideas as to what I should try?
I also tried compiling g++ separately into a .o file like
g++ -lgdi32 -c CImg.h -o a.o
which works
then
hipcc base.cpp -lgdi32 -o a.exe a.o
This time, I get the same error as last time with more warnings of the form:
warning: null character ignored [-Wnull-character]
  ...<U+0000><U+0000><U+0000>__SHRT_MAX__ 0x7fff9<U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+000C><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000>__LDBL_MAX_

